# Matplotlib scatter plot vs imshow for data set with different binsize

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, scatter-plot, imshow

I need to produce an image like below with my own x(phase),y(energy) and c (chi) values.

[image: colormap]

My x(phase bins) have 10 equal binsize from 0 to 2.0 whereas the y value is a bit more complicated with 50 binsize

```
x = np.arange(0, 2.2, 0.2)
ymin = np.array([300,305,310,..400,410,420,..,500,520,..,600,630,..700,750,..3000])
ymax = np.array([305,310,315,..410,420,430,..,520,540,..,630,660,..750,800,..3500])
```

There is also my colormap array (chi) with the same binsize as my y values

```
c = np.random.uniform(low=-10, high=10, size=50)
```

So for each x value, there exist a colormap value, that should be "colored" between ymin and ymax (like the image above). **For instance for first x bin (0.0-0.2) and first y bin (300-500), the colormap is 8, so I want a pixel to be filled between these x and y values with an appropriate color map (red in this case).**

Based on what I read on the web, there is more or less two approach to produce such a plot.

First one is based on the python scatter function. My code and produced image is below

```
import matplotlib
sns.set_style("ticks")
sns.set_context("talk")
cmap = "seismic"
norm = matplotlib.colors.Normalize(vmin=-11,vmax=11)
def rep(phase1,phase2):
    ff = np.full(shape=len(emax),fill_value=((phase1+phase2)/2.),dtype=float)
    return ff

plt.figure(figsize=(16,9))
plt.rcParams["font.family"] = "Times New Roman"
ax = plt.subplot()
y = ((emin+emax)/2)/1000
x1,c1 = rep(0,0.2),chi1
x2,c2 = rep(0.2,0.4),chi2
x3,c3 = rep(0.4,0.6),chi3
x4,c4 = rep(0.6,0.8),chi4
x5,c5 = rep(0.8,1.0),chi5
x6,c6 = rep(1.0,1.2),chi1
x7,c7 = rep(1.2,1.4),chi2
x8,c8 = rep(1.4,1.6),chi3
x9,c9 = rep(1.6,1.8),chi4
x10,c10 = rep(1.8,2.0),chi5

xval = np.array([x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6,x7,x8,x9,x10])
cval = np.array([c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6,c7,c8,c9,c10])

for x, c in zip(xval, cval):
    ax.scatter(x,y, s=(x*y)*fig.dpi,c=c,cmap=cmap,norm=norm)

PCM  = ax.get_children()[2]
cbar = plt.colorbar(PCM, ax=ax)
cbar.set_label(r'$\Delta \chi$', rotation=90, fontsize=25)
cbar.ax.tick_params(labelsize=22)
cbar.set_ticks(np.arange(-10, 11, 1))


ax.set_xlabel(r'Phase $\phi$', fontsize=28)
ax.set_ylabel(r'Energy (keV)', fontsize=28)
ax.set_xticks(np.arange(0, 2.2, 0.2))
ax.set_yticks([0.2,0.5, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0, 2.5, 3.0, 3.5])
ax.tick_params(axis='both', which='major', labelsize=28)
plt.tight_layout()
```

[image: produced with plot.scatter]

However, it does not produce what I expected and creates circles at specific points instead of rectangular (filled values between x and y bins). I played with the "s" but didnt change the results. In [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14827650/pyplot-scatter-plot-marker-size/47403507#47403507), it shows how to produce a pixel (rather than circle) but it did not work for me and still produces circle.

There is also approach based on pyplot.imshow like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59365170/customized-colormaps-in-python-matplotlib) and [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/layer_images.html#sphx-glr-gallery-images-contours-and-fields-layer-images-py) but in there, they use a 2D (Z values) and I quite didn't understand how to integrate different colormaps in there.

What is the best approach to plot such image.

Comment: Did you try pcolormesh(xval,y,cval)?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Yes this could work